# Console Application gets Window Smartscreen Unrecognized Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I wrote a simple C++ Console Application in Visual Studios 2013, it was a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors for my friends to demonstrate C++ to them. Each of my friends downloaded the game over Skype, and tried to open the application. However, it didn't work, they are running Windows 8/8.1 and they got an error, Windows Smartscreen prevented a unrecognized app from starting. For the publisher it says Unknown Publisher. It was a simple error to remove just click more info and run anyway. This problem is however very annoying and if so I would like it to stop when my applications run on others computers. Could it just be the way I transferred the file to them? I have look everywhere on the internet but the closest thing I could find was how this happens to Windows Application in VS, how you need a Digital Certificate for Windows to trust you as a Publisher. If you would need to review my source code it is on Pastebin here:[Rock, Paper, Scissors Source Code](http://pastebin.com/i4WdWnqc)

Comment: Is that the exact thing the error said? Just "Unknown Publisher" and nothing else?

Comment: Sorry correction is said "Windows Protected your PC" underneath this error it says "Windows Smartscreen prevented a unrecognized app from starting" but  **For the Publisher it says Unknown Publisher**

Comment: If you want the publisher to not say Unknown Publisher, you need a digital certificate.

Comment: I thought a digital certificate was only able to be used by a ClickOnce Application?